# Unable to Edit or Delete an Apex Class

Tags: apex

I am facing a weird issue where i am not able to update or delete the apex class.

1. On trying to delete the class i am getting below error message

   > insufficient access rights on object id
2. On trying to update the class i am getting below error message

   > The file FSP_Edu_EventRelatedDetailsTest has been modified and
   >   cannot be saved. Replace contents with new revision now?

your suggestions are highly appreciated..

Comment: How are you accessing the class - is it by an IDE and which IDE is it?

Comment: DO you have Author Apex/ modify all permissions?

Comment: did you try to click compile all classes link?

Comment: @DaveHumm Sounds like a similar "error" I sometimes get in Sublime Text where a file is modified on the server, meaning I have to refresh metadata in order to make changes. I think you're on to something there.

Comment: what happens if you try in developer console?

Comment: Hi Everyone,

The Apex class i am trying to edit/Delete is visible only in Developer Console and is the same place where i am trying to delete from File option menu.

The interesting thing is that these files are not available when i try to view from SETUP--> Custom Code-->Apex Classes